# The problem that colab does not recognize gluonnlp, kobert, and transformers

Tags: google-colaboratory

This code worked fine until a few weeks ago.
But one day I got an error and added the code as follows

```
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
!sudo apt install python3-pip
```

`After using the above code to replace the python version of colab with 3.8.10

If I run the code below
`

```
!pip install mxnet-cu101 gluonnlp pandas tqdm sentencepiece transformers torch
!pip install git+https://git@github.com/SKTBrain/KoBERT.git@master

import gluonnlp as nlp
from kobert.utils import get_tokenizer
from kobert.pytorch_kobert import get_pytorch_kobert_model
from transformers import AdamW
from transformers.optimization import get_cosine_schedule_with_warmup
```

`

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gluonnlp'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kobert'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers'

There is a problem with not being imported.
`